# My GPU can switch between 2 vBIOSes using a physical switch. Can I check in Windows which version is currently active?

Tags: bios, gpu

I have a Powercolor Red Devil 6700XT with a physical switch between a default BIOS and a quiet bios. Is there a way to check whether the switch is in the default or the quiet BIOS position without physically opening the case? I know opening my case and visually verifying it is an option, but my computer is in a bit of an awkward position where I can't get close enough to the side of the case that the switch is on. I was able to flip the switch, but I wasn't able to see the tiny writing on the board that says the position. I would have to unplug all my cables and physically move my case to be able to see it properly, and that's something I'd rather avoid.

Edit: I found a picture of the switch online with the text in close up and was able to verify that the position the switch is in was the one I wanted. Still, I'd still like to know whether this question has an answer.

Comment: It's the same "BIOS", what changes is booting with or without a GPU specific splash screen.

Comment: [GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) can dump the bios from a card using the little arrow icon to the right of the BIOS version line. Perhaps you could set up a script that does a binary compare of the dumped BIOS with version you've dumped when the switch position is known?